# Unable to resolve google-chrome-extension CSP error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first chrome extensions, here is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "share2twitter",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "background": {"page": "index.html"},
    "permissions": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/*",
        "tabs"
        ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js","index.js" ]
    }],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/ 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src https://www.googleapis.com/"

}
```

https://github.com/kracekumar/share2twitter/blob/master/manifest.json and in debug mode I get the following error .

```
Refused to load script from 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?callback=jQuery17108621194534935057_1344774835421&{%22longUrl%22:%22https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups' because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

I looked into reference for mappy, stackoverflow.com and google official docs, nothing worked out. So I am asking help here.

Expected behaviour:
When I click on the extension , it tries to connect to goo.gl url shortner and displays alert box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths in source URLs are not allowed in Content Security Policy values. You'll need to use this in your manifest:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src https://www.googleapis.com 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src https://www.googleapis.com"`

[A Chromium bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128493) has been filed (and has some ongoing work) to better warn in this situation.